# C# Get CheckedListBox Items ValueMember

Tags: c#

Sorry for disagreement but today I  need your help... in C# ! And I don't find it here.

For the below code, I need to get CheckedItem ValueMember for put it in richtextbox or string var... Can you help me ?

Please note LogBox is RichtTextBox where I want to show the ValueMember from checkeditems.

```
    // Favorites items
    public class Favorites {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }

    // For fav array in json 
    public class GetFav
    {
        public List<Favorites> favoris { get; set; }
    }

    // Member 
    public class ListBox
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    // Insert json data in CheckListBox
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string fav = @"myjsonfile.json";

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fav);
        string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GetFav>(jsonString);
        int i = 0; 
        for(i=0; i< json.favoris.Count; i++)
        {

            chkList.DisplayMember = "Text";
            chkList.ValueMember = "Value";
            chkList.Items.Insert(0, new {Text=json.favoris[i].name,Value=json.favoris[i].url});
        }
    }

    // Need to get the ValueMember and DisplayMember
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i = 0; 
        for (i=0; i< chkList.CheckedIndices.Count; i++)
        {
            // logBox.Text += chkList.Items[i] + "\n";  show => { Text = Google, Value = google.fr } 
            //logBox.Text += (chkList.Items[i] as ListBox).Value + "\n";  //get an error
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Or, if you aren't getting any errors, what is happening that shouldn't?

Comment: -  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException

Comment: *This is like asking my son what he did at school*. So, where / when do you get that error? Is there any other information (eg an inner exception)?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand... mhhh a screenshot is better ? https://i.imgur.com/ZCyc8Os.png

Comment: Code is always better than pictures. In any case, according to your picture, `(chkList.Items[i] as ListBox) == null`. Are you sure the `as ListBox` construct is correct (even if you don't get a compile-time error)?

Comment: I' m not sure... ListBox contains my DisplayMember and ValueMember : 

        public class ListBox
        {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        }